# Form of government (-archy/-cracy) where the strongest rules

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm doing some research for a story and I'm trying to find the correct word for a form of government where the best fighter or the strongest person leads the rest.

The usual words for forms of government are derived from Greek words suffixed with -archy (ἄρχω, *árkhō*, "to rule") or -cracy (κρατέω, *krateo*, "to have power over"), as in:
- Monarchy (rule of one)
- Oligarchy (rule of few)
- Plutocracy (rule by the wealthy)
- Theocracy (rule by God)
- Anarchy (without rule)
- etc.

The only existing word that is close to what I want is 'Stratocracy' (from  στρατός, *stratos*, 'army'), which is rule by the military, but that seems like a different concept.

The Greek word for power is *kratos*, but 'Kratocracy' seems like a ludicrous word ("power power"). 'Might' or 'Strength' may be more appropriate, but that would be something like *dynamis* -> 'Dynamocracy', which also sounds silly.

Is there a proper word for this form of rule? If not, what would be an appropriate word to invent, in line with the current convention?

Comment: Greek for strong/mighty is 'ischyrós' (ισχυρός). Ischyrocracy?

Comment: as a metaphor "wolf pack" is used often for a group where the leader is the most agressive/best fighter. It's the most primitive form of organisation and precisely what all other forms of -cracy -archy (including hereditary rights) are trying to avoid. I'm not not sure we can call that sort of power "government" as there's no stability, it's more the "law of the jungle".

Comment: Though with a different suffix, I think you may consider: Tyranny: arbitrary or unrestrained exercise of power; despotic abuse of authority.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: that sounds like "rule by fish", somehow. :-)

Comment: @JPmiaou I, for one, welcome our new fish overlords

Comment: I don't have an exact suggestion, but I was very surprised by the [length of this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Forms_of_government).

Comment: Two observations: 1. strength is not always physical, so strongest <> best fighter.  2. one libertarian/anarchist argument is that the word you are looking for is **state**, since all state power is ultimately backed up by force in the face of challenge (don't pay taxes, we'll take your money and/or lock you up).

Comment: Rule by the strongest, most manly man would be _androcracy_, from the Greek word _andros_ (manly man), in contradistinction to _anthropos_ (generic man). Or in California, it night be termed _Schwarzeneggerocracy_.

Comment: Chuck Norris doesn't need any *ocracy* to rule by strength.

Answer (score 9):

According to wikipedia, [Kratocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kratocracy) is, actually, the word you're looking for. It's not much of an article (as of the time of this posting), but it says the definition is:

> Kratocracy, (from the Greek κρατερός krateros, meaning "strong"), is [...] government by those who are strong enough to seize power through force or cunning.

The references list the [Dictionary of Philosophy](http://www.ditext.com/runes/k.html) as the source.

Comment: I'm glad to see _kratocracy_ at least put forward as a legitimate option here, notwithstanding the questioner's rather airy dismissal of it at the outset of the original post.

Answer (score 6):

Greek for physical force (or violence, e.g., rape) is [βία](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3D*b%3Aentry%20group%3D19%3Aentry%3Dbi%2Fa), but that root does not seem to serve as first element in any English derivatives, per OED. *(Biarchy* exists but denotes “dual sovereignty, government by two”—i.e., not *bia-* + *-archy* but just *bi-* + *-archy.)*

But in Greek political philosophy, those who argue for rule by the *stronger* (like Thrasymachus in Book I of Plato’s *Republic,* and Callicles in the same author’s *Gorgias)* are arguing for that polity which goes by the name of *tyranny,* as exemplified (in *Gorgias)* by the régime of Archelaos of Macedon.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered autocracy?

[autocracy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/autocracy): Government by a single person having unlimited power; despotism; a country or state that is governed by a single person with unlimited power.

Comment: This would be my choice. Since the "autocrat" actually has the power *in and of himself*, it seems obvious to me the designation implies that he rules *because he has power/strength*.

Comment: It seems possible to have a system where rulership is determined by physical might without having it be an autocracy, per se - such a system could easily be hierarchical and representational, just as a plutocracy is not necessarily an autocracy in a strict sense.

Comment: Why does an autocrat have to be the one who is physically strongest? I'm sure there have been autocracies where this wasn't true.

Answer (score 2):

The strongest man in some form or other will always rule.

Throughout the history, changing social structures and cultural evolution created specific forms of leaderships which turned into governments.

In ancient times, when people were hunters and gatherers, tribes were small and ruled by the strongest male. The rise of agriculture began to change that mindset. People needed to be ruled by something more than physical power. It was necessary to impose rules with the increasing populations and needs.

In anthropology and in Freudian theory, the ancient tribes which were ruled by strongest males are called ***[primal horde](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/primal-horde)*** and this kind of ruling has the early senses of patriarchy.

> (In Freudian theory) a hypothetical patriarchal unit of prehistoric human social organization.

---

Also, ***chiefdom*** is somewhat used in this sense in the history for the tribal societies which are ruled by warrior [chieftains](http://moderntransformation.com/contents/ch-5-first-kings-and-tribal-chieftains):

> Tribal societies needed stronger leadership to defend themselves, retain access to grazing land, and develop the ability to raid villages and cities. The men became warriors, and warrior chieftains began to dominate tribal leadership. As manliness and fighting skills became more important, the position and authority of women receded into the background.

Comment: Hunter gatherers can but do not need to organize into tribes.  Hunter gatherer communities can have fluid membership, especially when they are nomadic, and in this situation there are typically no chiefs, either.  I would read "Nisa: The Life and Words of a !Kung Woman".  The wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter-gatherer makes many good points too.

Comment: @Merk: I did not mean all of them but thanks for the details. There were egalitarian tribes in the history also.

Comment: While I'm sure Obama could have beat McCain in a fight, I'm not so sure that Bush would have beat Gore. So I don't believe your premise that the strongest man always rules. The question is specifically about physical strength.

Comment: @Barmar: My first sentence is just an introductory wordplay. It is not about physical strength and it is not the answer by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, and perhaps not accurate to your question. But I was looking for a similar thing: "ruling of the best". Which is called [***aristocracy***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aristocracy).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

I think here the word should be '[Chirocracy](http://wordinfo.info/unit/2784/page:2)' which means govt by physical force.